# creating index for the following query

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID, RENTAL_ID

FROM Vehicle, Rental

WHERE Vehicle.VEHICLE_ID = RENTAL.RENTAL_ID;
```

Rental ID and Vehicle ID are primary keys in 2 different tables.

How would I go about this? Do I create 2 unique indexes separately and then NON-unique for the rest? or is there a way to combine this?

thank you!

Comment: Apparently you've edited your query - it's not clear to me why you would need an additional index here at all since the ones used in the join above are already primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You should write your query using explicit `JOIN` syntax and use table aliases:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Purchase_Date, p.QUANTITY
FROM CUSTOMER c JOIN
     PURCHASE p
     ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = p.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

The only additional index you need for this query is `purchase(customer_id)`.

Comment: the query was given the way I posted it. I just have to create index based on it, thanks regardless

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Non Clustered Index for the foreign key, i.e., Customer_ID in Purchase table.

Then implement the join as below:

SELECT c.Name, p.Purchase_Date, p.QUANTITY
FROM CUSTOMER c 
join PURCHASE p
On c.CUSTOMER_ID = p.CUSTOMER_ID